# Sub merchant to main merchant payment in braintree in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, payment-gateway, braintree

If sub merchant get cash payment and sub merchant dont have card.
In this condition,can he transfer money from his merchant account to main admin account?
Means i want to transfer sub merchant to main merchant without paymentMethodNonce .